# Error: Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "Case Studies"

Tags: templating, entrymodel

I'm new to Craft CMS dev and I'm trying to create a template using Twig and I'm getting this error: Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "Case Studies"

I have a reference in the view file:

```
{% for entry in entry.caseStudies %}
```

I'm assuming there's a config file or somewhere I can add this to the EntryModel but I'm not sure where this is in the default Craft installation. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You do not need to add anything to the model to access field properties/values — craft handles all of this for you. You may want to double check that the field `caseStudies` is defined (and spelled correctly), and that it has been added to the field layout of the entry in question.

Comment: What type of field is `caseStudies` and how are you defining the initial `entry`? You'll probably want to rename it to `{% for anythingBesidesEntry in entry.caseStudies %}` so as not to clobber the original `entry` variable name.

Comment: Thanks I think my understanding of the template system is a bit wrong, If I don't add field properties/values and sections in the model then where to I define them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome Ross! If you have 'Case Studies' as a **Section** and not a field, try changing your syntax to:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('caseStudies').find() %}

    {{ entry.title }}
    ...

{% endfor %}
```

---

Here's an updated example, showing an additional custom field...

```
{# Find all Entries in the Case Study section #}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('caseStudies').find() %}

    {# Display the entry's Title #}
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>

    {# Display the contents of the Intro Summary (plain text field) #}
    <p>{{ entry.introSummary }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I think my understanding of the template system is a bit wrong. I thought that if I added entry.caseStudies to the template then it would give the option for that field in the backend. Are there any guides/docs available on how to add Sections and Fields to templates?

Comment: The contents of a custom field are retrieved using tags WITHIN the for-loop. e.g. {{ entry.title }}. Check out: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries. Each field-type has a different syntax for rendering or making use of it's contents: https://craftcms.com/docs/fields

Comment: Thanks - But is it possible to create custom fields like {{ entry.variable }}